# objective c - An indexedTableView in multiple languages works in english, not in greek

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This app has an english and a greek UITableView component. I need the tableview to be indexed.

I have this code to make the indexes:

```
if (languageKey == 0) { //greek
        sectionTitleArray =  [NSArray arrayWithArray:[@"Α|Β|Γ|Δ|Ε|Ζ|Η|Θ|Ι|Κ|Λ|Μ|Ν|Ξ|Ο|Π|Ρ|Σ|Τ|Υ|Φ|Χ|Ψ|Ω" componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];

    } else {

        sectionTitleArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[@"A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z" componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];

    }
```

This works fine for the english. The greek indices are ok, but the sections are badly out of order.

The code to make the sections are as follows:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    return sectionTitleArray;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    return index;
}
```

I've also tried this method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
   return [sectionTitleArray indexOfObject:title];
}
```

Should I be doing something differently?

Thanks

UPDATE - Adding screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In what way are the sections out of order? Only when you select an index? Which section does it take you to? Or all the time (does the displayed section order match the index order)?

Comment: David I suspect you need to localise your data. Link to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/). When your `NSFetchedResultsController` returns a data set for your table view, I'd try to process the data based on an `NSLocale`, using an `NSSortDescriptor` method that includes a comparator. Not sure how to do this - this is more a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm adding a couple of screen shots to illustrate the problem (while I go through Andrew's link). @wain, when I tap A, I always go to A. When I tap M, I always go to θ (theta). When I tap Omega, I go to Ipsilon (looks like Y). So there is some order there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a workaround. Using [Matt Neuberg's technique](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/324881-core-data-and-localized-sort-on-ios.html), I made a coded array in english - the greek letters mapped to english letters. These indices are stored in the database. Special cases were:

"Ξ" to"Nb" (N and O were taken)
"Ά"to "A" (same for other vowels , E, I, O, Y), and
"Ώ" to "Z"

That fools the sort descriptor giving me the correct sequence.

You both pushed me in the right direction, so +1 each. Thanks